# Multiple programs installing python modules on computer, confusing the crap out of IDLE

Tags: python, matplotlib

Most of the programs I use for my work have independent python API's which do various things. The downside to this is that it appears that each program installs its packages wherever it wants. This is by way of introduction.

Now, I am trying to run matplotlib through IDLE. I ran a clean pip upgrade and the ran a clean install of matplotlib using pip in `cmd`. The commands I used were found in [this document](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/a15/Resources/Windows/SettingUpPython_Windows.pdf), page 13.

When I try to `import matplotlib` in IDLE, I get the following error message:

```
>>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib
  File "C:\Program Files\ParaView 5.2.0-Qt4-OpenGL2-Windows-64bit\bin\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 727
    except Exception, msg:
```

The path it points to is for an independent program named Paraview which has its own set of python modules. It looks like Paraview also has a definition for `matplotlib` but I don't want to use this one. A quick snip of the paths in IDLE shows:

[image]

It looks like IDLE is prioritizing the Paraview folder over the others. How do I get IDLE to disregard this folder and look into the matplotlib module I just installed by default? Also how do I prevent this unfortunate and seemingly unnecessary duplication of modules?

Comment: What is the PATH set to? If all the installations are resetting the PATH location, only the last installation would work in theory.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this would work, but a virtual environment might work so that it is pulling from the files in that virtual environment

Comment: I second the virtual environment comment. It's intended to avoid exactly this kind of problem.